# getDeliveredNotifications() returns an empty array in Ionic Vue with Capacitor

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I am using Capacitor Push Notification in my Ionic Vue project. I am able to receive push notifications and can click on them, but the getDeliveredNotifications() function returns an empty array. The push notifications are being sent from the customer's IO.

Here is my code:

```
    function monitorNotification() {
  if (!Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
    return;
  }

  PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
    deviceStore.setDeviceToken(token.value);
    deviceStore.saveDevice();
  });

  PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
    console.log('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });

  PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed',
    (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
      if (notification?.notification?.data?.message?.apns?.payload?.aps?.data?.go_to) {
        router.replace({ path: notification.notification.data.message.apns.payload.aps.data.go_to })
      }
      else if (notification?.notification?.data?.aps?.data?.go_to) {
        router.replace({ path: notification.notification.data.aps.data.go_to })
      }
    }
  );

  PushNotifications.getDeliveredNotifications().then((notifications) => {
    alert('notifications:  ' + JSON.stringify(notifications)) 
    // is empty array
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });


  PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
    (notification) => {
      // alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
    }
  );
}
```

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it? I am testing it on an Android system on a MacBook by connecting to my mobile. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`getDeliveredNotifications()` returns only those notifications that have not yet been opened and are still visible in the notification center. Your implementation looks right. It depends on when you call the method.

> Get a list of notifications that are visible on the notifications screen.

[Source](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications#getdeliverednotifications)